# Declared function not called

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function to fetch my data from backend. once the data is loaded i am calling a function which is sent as `callback`. but i am getting error as `undefined not a function`

here is the code:

```
var initDataTable = function () {

      var getDableData = function (url,callback) {
            $.getJSON(url)
              .then(function (data) {
                callback(data);
            });
      };

      return {

        init : function (dataAssests) {
          this.container = dataAssests.container;
          this.headerNames = dataAssests.names;          
          getDableData(dataAssests.url, this.dataReceiver); //getting required data
        },

        dataReceiver : function (data) {
            this.tableData = data;
            this.tableMaker(); //not calling error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.
        },

        tableMaker : function () {
          console.log(this.tableData);
        }

      };
};

//tabular data starts...
var dataAssests = {
                    container: $('.dataTable'), 
                    url : 'https://tcs.firebaseio.com/d/DocPageDetails/d/Organizations.json', 
                    names : ['Organization Name', 'Zip Code', 'Telephone', 'Organization TypeName' ]
                  };

var dataTableFrist = initDataTable().init(dataAssests);
//tabular data ends...
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwuxwhrp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that callback is not defined, it is inside `dataReceiver` where `this` is not referring to the object what you are expecting.

Since you are invoking the `callback` without a context, `this` inside `dataReceiver` is referring to the `window` object so `this.tableMaker` is undefined thus the error.

One possible solution is to use [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to pass a custom execution context to the callback method

```
getDableData(dataAssests.url, this.dataReceiver.bind(this));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwuxwhrp/)

Comment: can you correct / simplyfiy the way, that i am getting the data and calling the method. I find getting the data i use more code. especially avoiding callback and instead `return` the data?